# Having trouble in matrix creation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

I want to write down this algorithm in latex

[image]

I write down the code in Latex. This is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Algorithm EIF\_ initialize($ u_{1:t}$):
\item  \begin{gather}\begin{pmatrix} \mu_{0,x} \\ 
\mu_{0,y} \\ \mu_{0,\theta} \end{pmatrix}   =  
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}\end{gather}
\item for all control u_t = (v_t,\omega_t)^T do
\item  \begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{t,x} \\ \mu_{t,y} \\ \mu_{t,\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{t-1,x} \\ \mu_{t-1,y} \\ \mu_{t-1,\theta}  
\end{pmatrix} \plus \begin{pmatrix} 
-v_t/\omega_t sin\mu_{t-1,\theta}+ v_t/\omega_t 
sin(\mu_{t-1,\theta}+\omega_t\Delta t) \\ 
v_t/\omega_t cos\mu_{t-1,\theta} -v_t/\omega_t 
cos(\mu_{t-1,\theta}+\omega_t\Delta t) \\ 
\omega_t\Delta t 
\end{pmatrix}
\item endfor
\item return \mu_{0:t}
 \end{enumerate}
```

It throws many errors also the output is look like

[image]

Which is not exact.

Errors are like that:

```
Missing $ inserted. 

  \item for all control u_Command \item invalid in math mode. 


  \item Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. 

  \item \begin Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

   \item \begin Undefined control sequence. 


  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \plus
Command \item invalid in math mode. 

  \item Missing $ inserted. 

  \item e Missing } inserted. 

  \item e Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. 

  \item e Missing $ inserted. 

  \item return \mu Command \end{enumerate} invalid in math mode. 

  \end{enumerate} Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. 

  \end{enumerate}
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. 


  \end{enumerate} Missing $ inserted. 

\end{enumerate} Overfull \hbox (111.12874pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please help us help you and publish an full MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that.

Comment: Well, just by looking one sees that you often forget to switch to math mode, e.g. `\item for all control u_t = (v_t,\omega_t)^T do` should be replaced by `\item for all control $u_t = (v_t,\omega_t)^T$ do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to use math environments for "everything math", see the `$` I inserted.
2. I also replaced `sin` and `cos` with `\sin` and `\cos`.
3. There was also a `\plus` which I replaced with `+` (might be wrong).
4. I also removed one `\item` (might be wrong).
5. You can switch the equation numbers on/off with `gather`/`align` and `gather*`/`align*` (see code and result).
6. I also included real fractions. You might want to go back to the plain notation or `\nicefrac`.
7. I changed some fonts according to the example you gave. Please note that I used a dirty trick in the first line since many math typefaces do not cover bold italics. You might want to go back to `$ u_{1:t}$`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Algorithm EIF\_initialize(\textit{u}\textsubscript{1:\textit t}):} \slshape
    \item \begin{gather}
        \begin{pmatrix} 
        \mu_{0,x} \\ \mu_{0,y} \\ \mu_{0,\theta} 
        \end{pmatrix}
        =\begin{pmatrix} 
            0 \\ 0 \\0 
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{gather}
    \item for all control $u_t = (v_t,\omega_t)^T$ do
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \mu_{t,x} \\ \mu_{t,y} \\ \mu_{t,\theta}\\
        \end{pmatrix} 
        =\begin{pmatrix}
            \mu_{t-1,x} \\ \mu_{t-1,y} \\ \mu_{t-1,\theta} 
        \end{pmatrix}
        +\begin{pmatrix} 
            -\frac{v_t}{\omega_t} \sin\mu_{t-1,\theta}+ \frac{v_t}{\omega_t} \sin(\mu_{t-1,\theta}+\omega_t\Delta t) \\ 
            \frac{v_t}{\omega_t} \cos\mu_{t-1,\theta} -\frac{v_t}{\omega_t} \cos(\mu_{t-1,\theta}+\omega_t\Delta t) \\ 
            \omega_t\Delta t \\
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
    \item endfor
    \item return $\mu_{0:t}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but I guess you could replace the `gather` by ordinary `$....$` the more so since there were no equation numbers in the screen shot.